# Kivy: Stop a android service from main App

Tags: android, python, service, kivy, pyjnius

If the following is how you start an android service with Kivy, how do you stop a service from the front end? I already know how to make the service stop itself in the service, i want to stop it from the frontend:

```
from android import AndroidService
service = AndroidService('myApp', 'status: active')
service.start('service started')
self.service = service
```

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
from jnius import autoclass
service = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonService').mService
service.stopService()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use python-for-android's newer services api, which I recommend, you can manage the service via pyjnius as follows:

```
        from jnius import autoclass
        service = autoclass('your.service.name.ClassName')
        mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
        service.stop(mActivity)
```

If using the old way with the android module (which isn't that well supported right now), it looks like you should be able to call `service.stop()` on your AndroidService object.

Comment: Hi @incement what do you mean by this line: `service = autoclass('your.service.name.ClassName')` what is the `ClassName`. Do you mind typing it out as any random example?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to link to http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/#arbitrary-service-scripts, which explains how the service name is set.